# Check if arbitrary value is in Object Literal with const assertion

Tags: typescript

If I wanna check if a value is in Object Literal with const assertion, is there any best practice?

I wrote the 2 following functions, which one would be better? and is there better way than these?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA8gIwFYFNhQDIEsooE4CGANjALwwDeAUDLTAIIBcMA5ASwDQ10BCzLCTt1oBhfsBZUAvjAIQYoSFADcVKlACeABxTxkaTDnzEyMTTpAAzPanTZchIgG0A1ig1Wz2lJ8S3DDsQAumqK0DBYEH4G9sZEAGrEAK4oAIymABQAbsTM0HhYYADmAJTMOSSRNjFGjmQAfJTCMHgoUEl4YNXoAHQVKRAZ0Xa1xCU9hcBESQAmKIMVsvLDAXEl0qHg4ZErsY6J0ygATJkVeVAFxWUwi1W7oySkjdR0CluwRJGw5Ct9yfNDfQjQJEEpLGD5QpFJxBVSvVrtTowT7QCZgKazAEVdZSKhAA)

```
const ObjectLiteral = {
    A: 'a',
    B: 'b',
    C: 'c'
} as const;

type ObjectLiteral = typeof ObjectLiteral[keyof typeof ObjectLiteral]

const isObjectLiteralValue1 = (val: string): val is ObjectLiteral => {
    return Object.values(ObjectLiteral).includes(val as ObjectLiteral)
}

const isObjectLiteralValue2 = (val: string): val is ObjectLiteral => {
    const list = Object.values(ObjectLiteral) as string[];
    return list.includes(val)
}
```

Comment: I'm going to interpret this question as specifically about how to get `includes()` to work ergonomically, and not the overly broad version "is there any better way" which could mean all sorts of things.  See the linked questions/answers for information about that. [This code](https://tsplay.dev/WokGLW) is probably how I'd do it.